# How to use Simplescalar, sim-outorder simulator to correctly model "my" systems specs (intel i7) with configuration files?

Tags: cpu-architecture

That is, how can I correctly/accurately model my systems specifications using sim-outorder configuration files?? The parameters in the default configuration file are nowhere to be found in i7-3610QM data sheets. I mean accept maybe L1 and L2 instructions and data cache specs. I know we an use -dumpconfig option to "supposedly" output "my" systems configuration file, but the file looks almost the same as the default, the defaults have not changed accordingly to my system. I can't figure this out, the documentation is vague and/or none existent.

Thanks
ThoughtMaze

Comment: Yeah was afraid no one knows...damn

Comment: It's not just a matter of parameters, simple scalar is a rather old simulator, and the developers didn't have any secret knowledge on micro-architectural features CPU companies really build internally. At best, you'll be able to model some of the behavior using the data sheets or Agner Fogs docs.

Comment: piece of junk, don't know why we learning it then

Comment: Because there's no publicly available simulator that does include everything that's inside. Simple scalar is good for a reasonable estimation.

Comment: answer, not accepted